# MS Word 2016 Headings & Multi List numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I would like to create the following multi-level list on MS Word 2016, where based on the heading number, the second number after "StandardText" will be the same.

An example:

[image: Example of the list]

I searched through google and here on superuser but cannot find how I can make it or if it's even possible to happen. Any reference links or videos are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a bit of work, but you could replace your regular numbered lists with Sequence fields (see [here](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008180_Numbering_with_Sequence_Fields.html) for a tutorial), and use the `\c` switch (explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be)) to repeat an already-used list number.

(There is also the ListNum field available for custom lists, as reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-new-bullets-numbers-and-multilevel-lists-6c06ef65-27ad-4893-80c9-0b944cb81f5f), but as far as I can tell, that doesn't allow for repeating list numbers.)